# Recurring calendar event not shown on correct days

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, calendar

I set up a recurring event on my Calendar list

Title - test
Start time 10/31/2011 11:00 AM
End Time 2/1/2050 12:00 PM
Recurrence Every 2 weeks on: Tuesday

On the Month view of the calendar i expected to see the event shown every two weeks on Tue but instead the "bar" stretches across everyday from 10/31/2011 - 2/1/2050.  Why is and is there a way to make it only show up on the tuesday for the week that it is scheduled?

Comment: Did you perhaps make it an all day event? Also, try to make it a never ending recurring event.

Comment: It is a never ending recurring event that is supposed to happen every two weeks on Tuesday.  I would expect it to show up on the cell for those Tuesdays.  Instead it stretches across the entire month.  This is a Default Calendar list using the default calendar web part.  I only want the event to display on the day in question.  Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<View List="$Resources:core,lists_Folder;/PpmCalendar" BaseViewID="2" WebPartZoneID="Left" Type="CALENDAR" Scope="Recursive" RecurrenceRowset="TRUE" />
```

Adding Scope="Recursive" and RecurrenceRowset="TRUE" attributes fixed it in the Elements.xml file of the module

Answer (score 3):

Try adding the below

For RECURRING EVENTS:

======================

Gotcha.. For recurring events issue, i have found a solution , as instructed in the msdn..

Need to change the SPquery little bit as given in the post,

[googledotnet.blogspot.sg/2012/11/recurring-events-not-working-in.html](http://googledotnet.blogspot.sg/2012/11/recurring-events-not-working-in.html)

Thanks